# Download an image on screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, download

How would I download an image to a users computer using javascript? the image is already on screen, but I want them to be able to click a button so that the native download option from each browser is used. (no need for ajax as the image is already there)

Any ideas?

Comment: right-click -> save as?

Comment: I'm expecting some users will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution

After finding out that you cannot do this with Javascript alone, I'm just setting the correct headers on the server.

in php, use these headers to return the image

```
$headers = [
  'content-type' => 'image/jpg',
  'content-disposition' => 'attachment; filename="photo.jpg'
];
```

Now, when `window.location` is set, it will just download the image - exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A pure left mouse click is not possible, since JavaScript can not set the necessary HTTP headers. Maybe this will be changed in the future - "HTML5".

Comment: This is correct. I was assuming this would be possible with Javascript alone. :(

Comment: I checked it some time ago for the same reason... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, insread of Using URLs for using them.. Use, Data URIs for them.......

You can open an image and then base64 it..

Now, add it instead of the Javascript file (like data:image/png; base64, ....................)

When clicked, set window.location.href to that data URI and it will be downloadable